# how do I add a field set to a custom visual force page running a quote wizard

Tags: visualforce-component, fieldsets, quote-template

I am new at this, 10 days on the job, so, please forgive me if I am asking something obvious.

I have a Custom Visual Force Page that runs within a QuoteWizard.  I need to add some fields to this page, and, I was thinking the best way was to create a field set, and add that to the page, but, I haven't figured out how to do that yet, lots of information on the internet, but, I haven't been able to nail down the exact issue I am dealing with.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

[**Field sets**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) can be directly referenced in Visualforce by combining the $ObjectType global variable with the keyword FieldSets. For example, if your Contact object has a field set called properNames that displays three fields, your Visualforce page can reference the field data through the following iteration:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.properNames}" var="f"> 
        <apex:outputText value="{!Contact[f]}" /><br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

you can access the labels and data types for the fields in properNames like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Fields in Proper Names">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.properNames}" var="f">
            <apex:column value="{!f}">
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column value="{!f.Label}">
                <apex:facet name="header">Label</apex:facet>
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column value="{!f.Type}" >
                <apex:facet name="header">Data Type</apex:facet>
            </apex:column> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```